# Adding A Static Page to Logged in User using Keystone.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, keystonejs

I am brand new to node and keystone so please bear with me if this is a rookie question.

I am trying to add a static page to the keystone admin panel so that when a user is logged in, only then can they access the static page (it will contain a google analytics API so that the user can track their reporting from the site). I am having no trouble with creating static pages for a non-logged in user, but I cannot find where the logged in nav structure is nested in my app or how to set a view so that only a user who is signed in can see it.

Comment: Add code snippet please.